# Action bar being shown below its tabs

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

When i set these attributes:

```
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("Title");
    actionBar.setLogo(null);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

The **ActionBar** is below its **Tabs**.

But if i comment this Like:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

It works fine. But the reason i want it to be **false** is, to avoid the appIcon being shown.

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I googled this problem and found this thread on gitub: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/327

You can read the thread, but the conclusion is:

> Hi. Just found a simple workaround.
>
> Use the following in your onCreate method :
>
> View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home); 
>  
> ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE); 
>
> this collapses the home button completely.
>
> PS : i'm using standard ActionBar but this should work the same

I hope this helps you out,
Daniel.

Comment: But will the HomeAsUpIcon also be hidden? **<** up icon must be visible, but not the appIcon

Comment: I can't find specific answers to this in the developers guide. But that will probably be gone too. I would say, try it. Otherwise you can maybe create some other workaround with a tiny transparant image, and place that as app icon in the action bar. (If this not affects the real icon). Then you only see the < displayed. But i think not this is the way android wanted it to be.

Comment: with ActionBarSherlock, use this: 
View homeIcon = findViewById(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? android.R.id.home: R.id.abs__home);

Answer (score 1):

i used this, and it's work on me

```
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    ab.setLogo(null);

    View homeIcon = findViewById(
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? 
            android.R.id.home : R.id.abs__home);
    ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((View) homeIcon).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

All  post above collapsing the home icon but leaving a blank space. For avoiding that you need to set the logo size to zero . Below added my code snippet.it may help for others who struggle with same problem.thanks

```
       actionBar.setLogo(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

      View homeIcon = findViewById(
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? 
                android.R.id.home : R.id.abs__home);
        ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, 0));
        ((View) homeIcon).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```