# Add custom title bar using ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, custom-titlebar

I want to add a custom title bar in a child of FragmentActivity, I have a layout for title bar and this is how I do it.

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.title_bar);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab0").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(this));
```

but the problem is title bar is showing below the tabs. I want the title bar above the navigation tabs.

this is my title_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/titleBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/titleBarMenuBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_btn" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleBarLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/titleBarMenuBtn"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16dip" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleBarUpdateDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/titleBarMenuBtn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titleBarLocation"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Updated: 30/Jul/2013"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082777/i-need-action-bar-tabs-with-custom-title-bar-android) post but my tabs are showing above title bar.

Thanks

Comment: There is a way to solve this problem, please refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760325/action-bar-being-shown-below-its-tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing the tabs above your custom layout is the intended default behaviour. Though there are ways to override this. I found to post with possible solutions: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710404/1965084) and [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12286559/1965084)

Further more the sherlock actionbar seems to behave the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... does it mean I will have to make custom title bars with tabs in it and will have to add the functionality to handle the swipe and tab position change?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the best solution (refering to solution #1). You should keep in mind, that you override the system default (and user expected) behaviour. Thats why its a bit more complicated :)